# What does this error mean and how do I solve it: error LNK2005: "<symbol>" already defined in <file.obj>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, sfml

Currently, I'm working with SFML in Visual Studio 2017, and using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxb0GvBNOGU&list=PL6xSOsbVA1eb_QqMTTcql_3PdOiE928up&index=4) on part 2. I've had success so far, but I tried to launch the final product of the video and got these errors:

```
1>Main.cpp
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Game::Game(void)" (??0Game@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Game.obj
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall Game::~Game(void)" (??1Game@@UAE@XZ) already defined in Game.obj
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "private: void __thiscall Game::initVariables(void)" (?initVariables@Game@@AAEXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "private: void __thiscall Game::initWindow(void)" (?initWindow@Game@@AAEXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Game::pollEvents(void)" (?pollEvents@Game@@QAEXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Game::render(void)" (?render@Game@@QAEXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool const __thiscall Game::running(void)const " (?running@Game@@QBE?B_NXZ) already defined in Game.obj
 1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Game::update(void)" (?update@Game@@QAEXXZ) already defined in Game.obj
```

From my understanding, it's saying that I'm trying to describe everything in `main.cpp` that's already defined in `game.cpp` (or `.obj`, I don't know what that is, I think it's just a compiled version of the code).

Here's my code:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.cpp"

int main()
{
    //Init game
    Game game;

    while (game.running()) //Checks if window is open
    {
        game.update();
        game.render();
    } 
}
```

Game.cpp

```cpp
#include "Game.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> 
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

//if there isn't a comment then don't modify it

void Game::initVariables()
{
    this->window = nullptr;
}

void Game::initWindow()
{
    this->vidMode.height = 480;
    this->vidMode.width = 640;
    this->window = new sf::RenderWindow(this->vidMode, "gaymer time", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Resize);
}

Game::Game()
{
    this->initVariables();
    this->initWindow();
}

Game::~Game()
{
    delete this->window;
}

const bool Game::running() const
{
    return this->window->isOpen();
}

void Game::pollEvents()
{
    while (this->window->pollEvent(this->event)) //Does sumthin idk
    {
        switch (this->event.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            this->window->close();
            break;
        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                this->window->close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Functions
void Game::update()//Updates game (does the actual gamer stuff)
{
    this->pollEvents();
}

void Game::render()//Renders game (just puts the pixels on the screen)
{
    this->window->clear(sf::Color::Transparent); //Clear old frame

    //Draw new frame

    this->window->display(); //Displays new frame
}
```

Game.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> 
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

class Game
{
private:
    //Private Variables
    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    sf::VideoMode vidMode;
    sf::Event event;

    //Private Functions
    void initVariables();
    void initWindow();
public:
    //Constructors/Destructors
    Game();
    virtual ~Game();

    //Accessors
    const bool running() const;

    //Functions
    void pollEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
};
```

If you need any more info, just ask.

Comment: You need to edit the errors and the code to reproduce them into the question. Read through how to make a [mcve] for advice.

Comment: @RetiredNinja He did, its in the pastebin.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The code and errors belong *In the question*, not at an external link that can go bad leaving the question worthless.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I see Remy and I learned a few things today about how stackoverflow works :) He now has a good minimum bit here, and I learned that refering to external links is not recommended

Comment: @PepijnKramer that I learned? Perhaps you meant Aidan instead?

Comment: @Remy ehr... yes I meant Aidan ;)

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT include source files in other source files.

In this case, the code in `game.cpp` will be compiled twice, once into `main.obj` and again into `game.obj`. Then the linker will combine the `obj` files and find the duplicate definitions, thus the errors.

In `main.cpp`, use `#include "Game.h"` instead of `#include "Game.cpp"`

Comment: thanks, it worked but why did it, just wondering

Comment: I'll try explaining. Each cpp file is compiled to an obj (intermediate binary) file. include literally makes the other file visible to compilation and any source code included will be compiled into the obj file. Say first game.cpp is compiled to game.obj then everything of the game class makes it into game.obj. Then main.cpp is compiled and everything in main.cpp AND game.cpp (because of the include) is compiled into main.obj.
Now the linker has to make an exe from both game.obj and main.obj and it finds all kinds of duplicate symbols (class/function names) and will complain.